# Shell Script output in Mac Shortcuts

Tags: shortcuts-app

In the Shortcuts app, how do I interact with the output of a shell script?
I can display the standard output, but I can't find a way to:

- use a path as a file (e.g. show file in finder, open file, etc.)
- loop over a list (outside the shell script, with the "Repeat with each" action

Any thoughts?

[image: shortcuts-app]

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to use "Shell Script Result" with `echo -n`, e.g.

[image]

I needed to use the `echo -n` because if I just used `echo` then I got a `?` (question mark) appended to my script's output.